# BSOD, Fatal System Error on Boot to Vista

Tags: boot, windows-vista, bsod

My HP Pavilion Elite m9400t is booting to a BSOD in normal mode, safe mode, or even System Recovery from the BIOS. When I disable  automatic reboot on system failure, I can see that this is the error :

```
STOP: c000021a {fatal system error}
The initial session process or system process terminated unexpectedly with a status of 0x00000000 (0xc0000034 0x00106e0). 
The system has been shut down.
```

When I run a diagnostic from the BIOS, i see at failure on the Boot path test.  Here is that error :

```
Error Code  : BIOHD-4
Error : Uninitialized /corrupt boot structure detected.
```

I don't have a recovery CD, but I have Win7 PC that I can use to make disks or bootable usb drives.  I know I should be trying to boot into a recovery mode and run some repair tools, but I don't know how to get there.  Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your system either has bad sectors on the drive, or a corrupted boot sector. Try downloading the Ultimate Boot CD and running some drive diagnostics on it.

Comment: I have a bootable Ultimate boot CD.  I see a lot of brand specific HD diagnostics in here.  Also scary things like "Reset MBR to zero". I have a generic brand HDD, so Im not sure where to go from here.  There is one tool that will do a surface scan but that seems fairly irrelevant. Any ideas?

Comment: You should have the MHDD32 utility on there. That should do it.

Comment: THanks for the reply Tom.  When I try to select any drive in MHDD, i see primary controller, secondary controller and PC3000 board, each  with no information below. When I try and select 1,3, or 5 and do a scan or init, or most other functions, it says "Drive not ready".   Any ideas how to proceed ?  I obviously dont have familiarity with this utility. Thanks again for your help !